# Is there a noticable difference between innodb and XtraDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, xtradb

Today on serverfault I read about XtraDB.
I read that it was a fork of innoDB and was woundering how big are the differences? 
Would I notice the change or do you think its just wasted time if I would try it out?

Answer (score 5):

XtraDB is designed to be a drop in replacement.  Most of the enhancements either fall under the category of better diagnostics, or improved scalability.

You can see a list of enhancements on the Percona blog:
http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtradb:patch:start

It doesn't hurt to try XtraDB and see.  If you don't like it, the file format doesn't change (unless you enable extra undo slots) so it's very easy to switch back.